# Jade causing error on local machine but not on demo website

Tags: pug

I run this

```
mixin eventpics(pics)
  .eventpics
    each p in pics
      .col-xs-4
        img.img-responsive(src=p)
- var event_pics = ['a', 'b']
+eventpics(event_pics)
```

on the [jade demo page](http://jade-lang.com/demo/) and it works just fine, but when I try to use the jade command line tool to output the html I get this error

```
TypeError: jade/myfile.jade:12
    10| mixin eventpics(pics)
    11|    .eventpics
  > 12|       each p in pics
    13|          .col-xs-4
    14|             img.img-responsive(src=p)
    15| 

Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Object.eval (eval at <anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade/lib/index.js:190:8), <anonymous>:20:31)
    at Object.jade_mixins.eventpics (eval at <anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade/lib/index.js:190:8), <anonymous>:57:4)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade/lib/index.js:190:8), <anonymous>:666:25)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade/lib/index.js:190:8), <anonymous>:1937:22)
    at res (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade/lib/index.js:191:38)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade/bin/jade.js:190:48
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:47:26
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

Comment: What's in `pics`, what code produces it? Whatever it is, the error indicates that it's `undefined`.

Comment: Starting to narrow it down a bit, when I run it alone in its own file it also works with the command line tool, must be some issue above this that isn't being caught until the each iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out the issue. I didn't include all of my code in the example and it turns out I should have. I was extending a layout.jade file and I had defined all of the `- var foo = bar` inside the file that was extending it. That made them undefined in the layout.jade file unless I defined a block `block vars` inside layout.jade and then put the variables inside that block in the file that was extending it.
The solution looked like this:

`layout.jade`

```
block vars
block content
```

`extending.jade`

```
extends layout

mixin eventpics(pics)
   .eventpics
      each p in pics
         .col-xs-4
            img.img-responsive(src=p)

block vars
   - var event_pics = ['a', 'b']

block content
   +eventpics(event_pics)
```